# A poset, all of whose nonempty subsets have a maximum and a minimum, is finite

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let $X$ be a poset such that all nonempty subsets of $X$ have a maximum and a minimum.

Show that $X$ is finite.

Comment: Can you show that $X$ is totally ordered?

Comment: This is obvious. Any two elements of $X$ are comparable (otherwise consider them together as a set, it will have no maximum or minimum).

Comment: What context is missing in this question?

Comment: You should address your question to the people who voted to close, I can only guess. You could have told us some motivation for the question—is it an exercise from some book? what book? You could have told us what progress you'd already made, so we don't have to repeat it. E.g. you might have told us that you noticed that your condition inplies that $X$ is totally ordered. Therefore, no need to drag posets into the discussion, it's a question about **totally** ordered sets.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Since you’ve already shown that $X$ is linearly ordered, you can argue as follows. Let $x_0=\min X$. If you’ve already defined $x_k$ for $k<n$, and $X\ne\{x_k:k<n\}$, let $x_n=\min(X\setminus\{x_k:k<n\})$. If at some point $X=\{x_k:k<n\}$, you’re done. Otherwise ... ?